# Populate multiple div tags with one AJAX html result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to find a way to populate the content of multiple div tags with HTML results I get from a single AJAX response.

Example:

- The target page has div tags with ID div_1, div_2, div_3 in a container div_page.
- The AJAX html response contains div tags with resp_1, resp_2, resp_3.
- I now want to put the data of resp_1 into div_2, resp_2 into div_1, and resp_3 into div_3.

Does jQuery help to solve this, how can I handle this? I am thinking about just adding the whole response to div_page and the copying the data, then removing the handled elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your response looks like

```
<div id='div1'>foo</div><div id='div2'>bar</div><div id='div3'>Foobar</div>
```

You can parse the response using .filter() and access the inner html using .html()

//Assuming var response is the html from the ajax request

```
let div1 = $(response).filter("#div1").html();
let div2 = $(response).filter("#div2").html():
let div3 = $(response).filter("#div3").html();
```

I've made an example for you here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqJLee

Comment: Completely understood, however, this means changing the server response from HTML to JSON - which I did not want to do... Is there a way to extract parts of the HTML although it has not been added to the DOM yet?

Comment: @RalfJahr i've updated the answer and that should solve your problem. Take a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you easily do that with jQuery.Assuming the resp_1 is html then you can do something like below.

```
$("#div_1").html(resp_1);
```

more help over [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)